# Как поместить кнопку в groupBox? Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я создаю groupbox и следом за ним кнопку. Кнопке я ставлю в скобках отображаться в groupbox'e, но она там не отображается или выдает ошибку, пробовал в скобках писать просто groupBox2 не получается. Как сделать так чтобы кнопка была привязанна (находилась) в groupbox?[image]

Comment: Что делать?  Предоставите [mcve]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, не нужно в кнопку передавать рамку. Посмотрите материалы про макеты QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout и QGridLayout.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class GroupBox(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("GroupBox")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        groupbox = QGroupBox("GroupBox Example")
        layout.addWidget(groupbox)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        groupbox.setLayout(vbox)

        button = QPushButton("Button 1")
        vbox.addWidget(button)
        
        
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = GroupBox()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а если передавать рамку в кнопку, то ваш код работает или нет?

Comment: S. Nick, я если честно так никогда не делал, и в учебнике pyqt посмотрел, такого я там не нашел) Т.С. спросил "Как сделать так чтобы кнопка была привязана (находилась) в groupbox?", я написал свой вариант. Если кто-то напишет пример "рамку в кнопку" я бы посмотрел, ввиду не достаточности собственного опыта.

Comment: я просто предложил вам попробовать добавить и сказать что у вас получилось. В вашем случае, когда вы добавляете кнопку в менеджер компоновки, это действительно не имеет смысла, так как после добавления кнопки в layout - менеджер компоновки становится хозяином этой кнопки и управляет ею.

Comment: S. Nick, я пробовал, но что то у меня никак это не получилось(